# One to many reversed relation?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a special setup for my database. ( see screenshot attached )

> So I have realisations, and projects and they can have a gallery on attached to them, the gallery contains pictures.

Now I can't seem to make the relation that if I delete a realisation, or a project, the gallery attached also is removed.

I have tried both combinations of foreign keys, on the galleries table, and on the realisations / projects table.

Any idea what might I'm overseeing? Thank you!

[image]

This is the SQL I tried

```
ALTER TABLE `galleries`
ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_galleries_realisations` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `realisations` (`gallery_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

And this is the error I get when I try to create a new realisation

```
Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`elbeko`.`galleries`, CONSTRAINT `FK_galleries_realisations` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `realisations` (`gallery_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE) (SQL: insert into `galleries` (`name`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Tester, 2015-10-16 08:53:28, 2015-10-16 08:53:28))
```

Comment: Well the code is in laravel ( migrations ) but it's more a question about the logic. On which table should the relation reside, is more my question. thank you.

Comment: tried that but got an error, I'll add my code to the question, 1min!

Comment: I added more explanation. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its not a special but "potentially" dangerous architecture you have there.
According to your diagram many projects could point to a single gallery and you don't want to delete a gallery if one project is deleted. Because other projects "could" still use that specific gallery.

You can either modify your gallery table so each gallery record points to a project/realisation ID/UUID so you can take advantage of cascading.

if you really want to delete gallery record, use a trigger "After delete"
and perform.

1. Set gallery_id = null on all other records inc. other table
2. Delete from gallery table
3. where gallery_id = old.gallery_id

again... very dangerous imho.

if you want to normalise your tables, you can simply create two gallery table for each project and realisations **OR** you can take advantage of G/UUID's and have a single gallery table.

GUIDs are said to be globally unique identifiers. MSSQL calls it GUID, MySQL calls it UUID (universally unique identifier)

GUID's are used to have unique ids throughout your application. In your case, since project_id and realisation_id could have same value, you can't use the this field as a common foreignkey in gallery table.

To have single gallery table and use GUIDs

1. Add a new field called project_uuid varchar(36) not null default "0"
2. Add/modify "before insert" trigger on your tbl_project table

> ```
> if(length(coalesce(new.project_uuid,'')) <> 36) then
>   set new.project_uuid = (select UUID());
> end if
> ```
>
> This will generate new GUID everytime when you insert a project record.

3. Assign new GUIDs for existing project records by

> ```
>  Update tbl_project
> set project_uuid = (Select uuid())
> Where tbl_project.project_id >= 1;
> ```
>
> Now all of your existing project records have an unique GUID assigned

1. Do the same for realisation table
2. Now add a new field owner_uuid varchar(36) in your gallery table
3. Ideally your gallery table structure would look like this

> ```
> Gallery_id int, not null, primary, auto increase
> owner_uuid varchar(36) ' usually second primary but for the migration it can be null
> gallery_name ....
> ...
> ```

1. Now you need to replace the old IDs with the unique GUID

   > ```
   > Update tbl_gallery inner join tbl_project on tbl_project.gallery_id = tbl_gallery.id
   > SET owner_uuid = tbl_project.project_uuid 
   > Where tbl_gallery.owner_uuid is null;
   > ```
2. Do the same for realisation table

Now you can have simple 1:N cascading relationship between project <> gallery and realisation <> gallery tables.

now when you create a gallery record you will use

```
Insert into tbl_gallery(id, owner_uuid, name)
VAlues(
null, 
either project_uuid or realisation_uuid
name );
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm aware of the weird database structure. But i'm thinking if i want to add an ID of the realisation or project there will be duplicate id's right? thank you for the great answer

Comment: are you allowed to modify your tables? @Notflip

Comment: Offcourse! :) I'd be happy to.. But don't really know how to implement your idea. so that I indeed can use cascading. because a project id can be the same as a realisation id.

Comment: Gallery record can't exist without a project, so the gallery table should have gallery_id, owner_id (project_id/realisation_id). the simplest way is to have two gallery tables for each of your tables. if you only want to have one gallery table you need to use G/UUID instead ID.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, what do you mean with 2 gallery tables for each of my tables? Like realisation_gallery, projects_gallery, .. I think the better option is using the owner_id? thanks!

Comment: yes either two tables, or owner_id but instead id you have to use GUID to get rid of the duplicate project_id, realisation_id. This will require, modify all of your three project, realisation, gallery tables.

Comment: What do you mean by GUID?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92472/discussion-between-krish-km-and-notflip).

Comment: Thank you so much! Never heard of uuid, I got it working now!